# how do i get the select value not the option value in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi can some one help me to my problem.

I have a html and php function here all i want to to is to echoed a select value not the option value

here is my code
Ouput: Patrick or any for the name when I select and send the button

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['send'])){echo $_POST['test'];}?>
<form method="post">
<select name="test"><option value="1">Patrick</option><option value="2">Maria</option><option value="3">Fe</option></select><input type="submit" name="send" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi can some one help me to my problem.

I have a html and php function here all i want to to is to echoed a select value not the option value

here is my code
Ouput: Patrick or any for the name when I select and send the button
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['send'])){echo $_POST['test'];}?>
<form method="post">
<select name="test"><option value="1">Patrick</option><option value="2">Maria</option><option value="3">Fe</option></select><input type="submit" name="send" value="submit">
</form>

Comment: Simple remove `value=""` in `<option>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['send'])){echo $_POST['test'];}?>
```

change the value of your option to you want to display

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="test">
        <option value="Patrick">Patrick</option>
        <option value="Maria">Maria</option>
        <option value="Fe">Fe</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="submit">
</form>
```

//change the $row['id'] to $row['name']

```
<?php $q = mysql_query("select * from name");?>
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){ 
     echo '<option value='.$row['name'].'>'.$row['name'].'</option>' ;
}
```

// ok you want to used the id in option value.in your submit code get the name for table check bellow code

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['send'])){$id=$_POST['test'];
$q = mysql_query("select * from name where id=$id");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
echo $row['name'];
}

?>
<?php $q = mysql_query("select * from name");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){ 
        echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['name'].'</option>' ;
}?>
```

Comment: Haha its very easy. but I dont think so this is the answer if you will be translating this one to php. <?php $q = mysql_query("select * from name");?>while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){  echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['name'].'</option>' } . I want to display the row of the name not the row id thanks

Comment: nice try sir but as I said on my previous statement the reason why i Include the row['id'] is that I will be using it for different functions. so I think my php query is correct but my problem is the value that my code is getting is the option value not the text value

Comment: @PatrickTandocSarmiento  if you want to used id in value at that time you get recode from database  in you post code check my last update code

Answer (score 1):

specify the value in option like this "1_Patrick"

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['send'])){
          $value = explode('_',$_POST['test']);
          echo $value[1];
         }

?>

<form method="post">
<select name="test"><option value="1_Patrick">Patrick</option><option value="2_Maria">Maria</option><option value="3_Fe">Fe</option></select><input type="submit" name="send" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the comment I already tried it and it works thanks

Comment: I change some coding from your jquery :) anyway this is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The value of the select will be whatever option is selected. If I select Maria, you will see 2 displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" align="center" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <select name="user" id="user_id" onChange="selectuser()">
                <option value="0">Select User</option>
                <option value="1">Patrick</option>
                <option value="2">Maria</option>
                <option value="3">Fe</option>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script language="javascript">
    function selectuser()
    {
        var name = $("#user_id option:selected").text();
        alert(name);
    }
```

Comment: Actually here is my code:if i will click the button of whatever the option i select it will display the name not the value<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><form method="post"><select  name="test"><?php $q =mysql_query("select * from name");while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
?><option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option><?php }?>
</select><input type="submit" name="send" value="submit">
</form><?php if(isset($_REQUEST['send'])){echo $row['name'];}?></script></body></html>

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<form method="post">
<select name="test">
<?php $q =mysql_query("select * from name");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['name']?>">
<?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
<?php }?> 
</select>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="submit"> </form>
<?php if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
 echo $_POST['test'];
}
 ?>
</script></body></html>

Answer (score 0):

when you post any form then data contained in the `value attribute` of the field will get posted.

So you can change the value data to the desired value, like value="Patrik"

As you said that there is purpose behind adding numeric data to value then my suggestion would be add this numeric data to some other custom attribute like `data-customid="1"` etc and change `value="Patrick"`

You can add custom attribute in option value.

Refer this [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) for details.

Answer (score 0):

pure js:

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/f5f83a65991675d93d6d701173eac29b)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function() {
      alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerText);
  }, false);

}, false);
```